# How to access an application with Okta authentication via curl?

Tags: curl, postman, okta

I have built an application based on Okta. When I access it from the browser, I get the correct results after I logging-in in Okta. When I use CURL/Postman, I, unfortunately, am not able to access the service. I first get a session token via CURL, and then I set this token in the cookie. When I try to access the service with the token, I get credential error results. 
Can someone help me in the structure of the messages that I have to send via CURL/Postman?